# Trigger event when an object's property changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, dom-events

Unsure about the correct terminology for this, but I'm working with a few APIs in NodeJS, as well as Mongoose. I have a stack of Mongoose records which have data from the Google Maps API being loaded into them, and I want to create a listener for each record to watch when a particular field is filled.

I can't do this via simple callbacks, as the APIs are rate limited and require an interval queuing system.

Instead I'd like something like:

```
 var obj1 = {name: 'rec1', mapData: {}, fieldData: {} };
 obj1.on('mapDataComplete', function(){...});
```

Where `mapDataComplete` is emitted when `obj1.mapData` changes from its initial state.

Comment: Sounds like what you really need is a river from MongoDB. There are several available as rivers are often used to update things like ElasticSearch automagically when the record in Mongo is updated.

Comment: Well one idea would be to use Object.defineProperty and override the set method to call ur method. So when u do obj1.mapData = 'whatever' it should pass through ur set method. I think some frontend frameworks like vue.js use this for data binding.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is Object.observe.

`var obj1 = {name: 'rec1', mapData: {}, fieldData: {} };
 Object.observe(obj1, function(change){...});`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

Comment: Object.observe proposal seems to be withdrawn. So using it wouldn't be ideal. https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe

Comment: I had no idea... Thank you for informing me :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. 
For now using [WatchJS](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS/) which works fine for me.

```
//defining our object however we like
var ex3 = {
    attr1: 0,
    attr2: "initial value of attr2",
    attr3: ["a", 3, null]
};

//defining a 'watcher' for the object

watch(ex3, function(){
    alert("some attribute of ex3 changes!");
});

//when changing one of the attributes of the object the watcher will be invoked
ex3.attr3.push("new value");​
```

If I had to implement it myself (I have no idea how WatchJS) works, I would probably wrap the pojo's properties with 'setter' and 'getter'.

If a property is an array, I would wrap it's splice, concat, push etc.. 
And make each one of those fire an event..

Might sound a lot of work at the beginning, but I am sure you can see results very fast.